# How to store chat message temporarily in file using nodejs socket.js?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js

I am currently working on a chatting client and server. My client says that they do not want me to store the chat messages in db. That should be temporarily.

How to do it? The Skype and WhatsApp store the messages locally. I need it like that.

Answer (score 0):

If temporarliy.

Then make use of **webSQL** or **indexDb** which will store data locally on devices.

Comment: I think it is a good way to store the data locally. i am gonna try it.thanks.